# Angular subscribe to observable then return a new one

Tags: angular, angular-observable

I'm using HttpClient to `get` data from a webservice.  I want to subscribe to the resulting data and convert it from JSON into actual classes, and then have an `Observable` of those classes returned from the method.  Basically when the caller's `subscribe` fires I want it to get the classes.

I'm pretty new to angular and observables, so I'm not sure how to do that chaining.  So I'm wanting something like:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getExistingArsByLab(labId: number) : Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]> {
    return this.http.get("...")
        .subscribe(json => json.map(obj => {
            let ar = new EhsAssessmentAr();
            ar.id = obj['id'];
            ...
            return ar;
    }));
}
```

which of course doesn't actually compile and then the caller would just do:

```
this.getExistingArsByLab(12).subscribe(ars => { ... });
```

and at that point I'd have `ars` as an actual `EhsAssessmentAr[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined with @Antoniosss answer, I think this should solve your problem:

```
getExistingArsByLab(labId: number) : Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]> {
 return this.http.get("...")
    .pipe(map(obj =>  {
        return obj.map(element => {
           let ar = new EhsAssessmentAr();
           ar.id = element['id'];
           ...
           return ar;
        });
 }));
}
```

Note that `map` from `Observable` is different than `Array.map()`

Answer (score -1):

Dont subscribe right away but `pipe` and `map`

```
getExistingArsByLab(labId: number) : Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]> {
    return this.http.get("...")
        .pipe(map(obj =>  {
            let ar = new EhsAssessmentAr();
            ar.id = obj['id'];
            ...
            return ar;
    }));
```

}

You must fix brackets and add proper mapping.

Comment: That seems to be returning just a single ar object instead of an array of them.

Comment: You should get the idea how to do that now.

Comment: Well not really because I'm confused why the compiler would be saying that it returns a single object and not multiple when map works against multiple objects.

Comment: It's how Rxjs works. `.subscribe` does not return anything while `.map` returns a new Observable which in turns matches with the return type of your method `Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]>`.

Comment: @ChauTran Right but the compiler says `Observable<EhsAssessmentAr> is not assignable to type Observable<EhsAssessmentAr[]>`.  So it thinks the map returns just a single object.  Sorry, I'm just not understanding.

Comment: Then fix it. I dont know what kind of structure is coming as http response.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what the client sends.  This is a typescript compiler error.

Comment: Because you `return ar` which you initialized as a single `EhsAssessmentAr`, not `EhsAssessmentAr[]`

Comment: And which part of that is confusing you here ?

Comment: I'm used to a map() method being passed each individual element.  Is the map here actually just getting the entire contents of the data returned from the webservice, and then I loop over them *inside* the map call and return an array then?

Comment: Besides, it as plenty to do with data structure, as normally, to avoid such compile time errors you would declare that structure (with interface) and cast actual response to it. Right now you are working with `any`.

Comment: *I'm used to a map() method being passed each individual element.* Who said that `json` is an array that you can `map` on?

Comment: This code is functionally the same as the one you have provided.